# AngularJs same controller in different pages doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs

I am making an AngularJs website where I have a login page and a main page.Main page will display some information related to the logged in user.  These 2 pages have the same AngularJs controller and app.

When user logs in, I save his/her id and name in two scope variables and those scope variables will be used in the **main.html** to retrieve data from the database.

In the login page, I put an alert box and checked those variables and I can see the values. but when the page is navigated to the main.html, I don't see any values in them variables.  I am very new to AngularJs so please provide me some easy solutions.

[image: code behind login button]

[image: code used in main page to retrieve data]

Please let me know if more code is required.

Comment: please share code what you have tried

Comment: please post code as actual code, not screenshots.

Comment: You can simply pass the same controller in the $stateProvider ,  in this way the controller would be accessible in both the pages.

Comment: you learn about $stateProvider otherwise $urlProvider and learn best practice

Comment: How do you change state from login to main page ?

Comment: Your problem is that while you are re-using the controller, it's creating a new one (by design) when you go to the other state. There are various methods you can use to make the data available to the other controller: use routing parameters (for ui-router or ngRoute), use a service to store the data and inject the service into the controller, etc.

Comment: Which router are you using? [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/)? Create a service to share data between different pages, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services).

Comment: i really have no idea on how to answer your guys questions. i dont use any routing. its just $window.location.href="main.html"; that i have used to go to the main page. i have used an app.service as well. i can assign values to it but it returns nothing. i am so confused with the way that angular js is working.

Answer (score 0):

best practice is to use a different controller for a different page. but if you want to use the same controller for a different page. you can use it like.  this is sample code with use of `ui-router`

```
$stateProvider
      .state('login',{
        url : '/login',
        templateUrl : 'login.html',
        controller : 'loginMainCtrl'
    })
      .state('mainPage',{
        url : '/mainPage',
        templateUrl : 'mainPage.html',
        controller : 'loginMainCtrl'
    })
```

if you are using `ngRoute`

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/login", {
            templateUrl : 'login.html',
            controller : 'loginMainCtrl'
    })
    .when("/mainPage", {
         templateUrl : 'mainPage.html',
         controller : 'loginMainCtrl'
    })

**hope this will help you..**
```

Comment: thank you for your reply.  

where should i put these codes? im a beginner to the angular js and still have no idea on where to put these codes.

thank you

Comment: you can refer this to understand routing of angular js. @SajadJaward.. if my and helped you. u can mark it up